# Ширина блока 100vw, выравнивание по центру

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

```css
main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: max-content max-content 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: min(100px, 70%) min(50px, calc(30% - 10px));
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: start;
}
.box1 {
   width: 100vw;
   grid-column: 1 / -1;
   background: tan;
}
.box2 {
   grid-area: 2 /1;
   background: beige;
}
.box3 {
   grid-area: 2 / 2 / -1;
   background: gray;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="box1">Блок 1</div>
    <div class="box2">Блок 2</div>
    <div class="box3">Блок 3<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br></div>
</main>
```

Блоки выравнены по центру, но первому блоку присвоено свойство 100vw. Как сделать так, чтобы выравнивание по центру не распространялось на 1 болок. Чтобы первый элемент занял всю ширину экрана, начиная от левого края?

Главное не меняя структуру html

Answer (score 0):

Может так

```
.box1 {
  justify-self: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Не срабатывает. Все на своем месте...

Comment: @Aleks, ты не совсем понятно сформулировал какой дизайн тебе нужен. Только догадываюсь.
У тебя 2 колонки, 3 ряда.
3 элемента, которые ты хочешь положить в грид. Если правильно понимаю, хочешь чтобы весь первый ряд занял box1.
Если так, то укажи box1:
`.box1 {
grid-column-start: 1;
grid-column-end 2;
}`

Тогда box2 и box3 займут 2-й ряд. Но тогда тебе не нужен 3-й ряд, поэтому может я ошибаюсь. Если не так, опиши понятнее какой дизайн тебе нужен.